# downloading big files in a limited wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, download

In our college wifi, maximum file size downloadable is 20mb. is there a way to download large files in 20mb blocks and combine later? any help on this is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is this a technical limit or a policy limit?

Comment: wget -c , but you don't say which OS you are using

Comment: @david-it is a policy limit. files larger than 20mb are not allowed to download somehow.but on sundays this limit does not exist.

Comment: @jet- i'm using windows 7. but a solution in Ubuntu would also be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a download manager like [FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com/index_en.html). They can often split downloads into chunks and recombine them later as you suggest. Whether or not this would be helpful in getting around your school's network policies depends on how they're set up, but it's worth a try.